# Does sitemaps have to have a capital S?

Tags: sitemap

Do I need capital S in `sitemap_index.xml` and `sitemap.xml` when submitting them, or doesn't it matter?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by submitting them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on the web server.

Some servers (e.g. Linux) differentiates between upper and lower case, so `Sitemap.xml` and `sitemap.xml` can exist in the same folder, and are separate from each other. Other servers (e.g. Windows) doesn't make a difference between upper and lower case, so `Sitemap.xml` and `sitemap.xml` reference the same file.

If you reference the site map from your `robots.txt` file, you can call it `Mamma.mu` if you lilke.

Answer (score 1):

If you submit the sitemap directly to a search engine, it does not matter at all.

Alternatively, you can declare the URL of the sitemap in your `robots.txt` like this:

```
Sitemap: <sitemap_url>
```

Using the full URL (including http:// prefix)

Comment: Url of sitemap_index or sitemap in the robots.txt?

Comment: @Camran: either is fine. The searchengine will recognize the type from the content.

Answer (score 0):

sitemap_index.xml should generally be in all lowercase at the root of your web server.  I don't believe any of the submission forms for search engines care what the filename is at all.